# How to target pseudo controls using type-safe css in Kotlin

Tags: css, tornadofx

For example if I want to change the default style of a selected button, if using external css would like

```
button:selected {
...
}
```

How to do it with type-safe css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`button and selected { }` will render as `.button:selected`.

The `selected` pseudo class comes with the framework, but you could just as easily have created your own. It's defined like this in the `Stylesheet` class:

```
val selected by csspseudoclass()
```

Comment: Ah, maybe it's not covered. A PR would be most welcome :))